# How to convert a TimePicker Value to a unix timestamp for Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, unix-timestamp, timepicker

uuhm..

I have another problem.
I need to convert a TimePicker (Windows Phone 7) Value to a unix timestamp..

How is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
DateTime selectedTime = ((DateTime) TimePicker.Value)

public static double ConvertToUnix (DateTime selDate)
{
    var unixStart = new DateTime (1970, 1, 1).ToLocalTime();
    return (selDate - unixStart).TotalSeconds;
}
```

Comment: it works, but i am not sure what does happen to leap seconds, they are not included in unix-time, but they are included in usual time, isnt it so?